# Write a bunch of entries from a log file into a txt file with a specific time range. (JAVA)

Tags: java

I have a log file and I want write it in a txt file with a time range. (JAVA).
For example, the log file is like:

```
    2014-04-11 00:00:02.134 [DEBUG] [SNGW-Deliv] [] asdf
    2014-04-11 00:01:02.135 [DEBUG] [SNGW-Deliv] [] qqqq
    2014-04-11 00:02:02.198 [DEBUG] [SNGW-Deliv] [] ffff
    2014-04-11 00:03:02.198 [DEBUG] [SNGW-Deliv] [] gggg
    2014-04-11 00:06:02.198 [DEBUG] [SNGW-Deliv] [] nnnn
    2014-04-11 00:06:02.198 [DEBUG] [SNGW-Deliv] [] rrrr
    2014-04-11 00:08:02.198 [DEBUG] [SNGW-Deliv] [] mmmm
    2014-04-11 00:09:02.198 [DEBUG] [SNGW-Deliv] [] kkkk
```

I want to write log entries through 2014-04-11 00:02:02.198 to 2014-04-11 00:08:02.198 into the .txt file. Does anybody can help me for this issue?

Comment: Is your issue reading the log file, gathering valid entries within your defined range or writing to the output text file? What have you tried? Can you show us your attempts?

Comment: I am writing to the output text file. I can write for a specific time now, but not for a time range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into an external library like [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)  (and use their DateTimeFormatter and Period class) or try using Java's [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to read and parse your input log file dates.

The following is somewhat psuedo-code but the lines that matters most to you the SimpleDateFormat and parse should work for your case.

```
SimpleDateFormat rawDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
DateTime logTime;
for (String logfileLine : logfileLines) {
    logTime = rawDateFormat.parse(stringDateFromLine);
    if (logTime > myPeriodStart && logTime < myPeriodEnd) {
        writeToOutputFile(logfileLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try Joda Time. There is one more problem. It seems some of the lines in the file are not starting with log times. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Firstly, are you sure the lines are new lines? Is your text reader displaying with word-wrap turned on? If not then I would assume that some log descriptions contain newline characters (and perhaps even tab characters). If your log file is in chronological order then you can add those lines along with the others and when you reach a line that has a time and is outside your range then stop. If you want to parse or handle the information inside those lines that is another story altogether. Please make a new question if that is the case.